# Why MySQL primary key need to hold a gap lock that cause a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, indexing, deadlock

I got the a deadlock issue ,but I have some comfuse .
The log show one session had hold a gap lock on primary key ,primayry key attribute is auto increment .

Why the session not used the record lock but also gap lock on primary key index ?

The deadlock info as below :

```
(1) TRANSACTION:
 insert ignore into lock_table(order_code, user_id) values ('ORDER20240101001', 6878711) ,('ORDER20240101001', 6878711) ,('ORDER20240101001', 6878712) ,('ORDER20240101001', 6878713) ...

(1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2008 page no 144450 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `oderdb`.`lock_table` trx id 74405516399 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting

(2) TRANSACTION:
 insert ignore into lock_table(order_code, user_id) values ('ORDER20240101001', 6713758) ,('ORDER20240101001', 6713768) ,('ORDER20240101001', 6713858) ,('ORDER20240101001', 8878713) ...

(2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2008 page no 144450 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `oderdb`.`lock_table` trx id 74405516397 lock_mode X locks gap before rec

(2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2008 page no 144450 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `oderdb`.`lock_table` trx id 74405516397 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
```

```
CREATE TABLE `lock_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_code` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `expire_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `modified_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_lock_table_01` (`user_id`,`order_code`),
  KEY `idx_lock_table_01` (`expire_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=151345693 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE lock_table` so we can see all the indexes.

Comment: I had updated the table structure .

Comment: Consider getting rid of `id` and promoting the `UNIQUE` to be the PK.